# How do I add a second key to my Matplotlib scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I have a Matplotlib scatter plot in which point markers vary by to attributes, shape and color, depending on the values of two attributes associated with the point ("Net Size" and "Batch Size" respectively), but using `legend` I can only seem to get a key for the first attribute:

[image]

How do I add a second key for the color (as a function of "Batch Size")? In fact, I'd also like the have the existing key just distinguish shape (no color), if that can be accomplished. I'm also happy to replace the colors with some (potentially more informative) grayscale or spectrum.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

batch_color_specs = ['r', 'm', 'b', 'y', 'g', 'k']
batch_sizes = [10, 20, 40, 80, 100, 200]

# Data below
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for net_size, net_size_mark, net_size_alpha in zip([30, 60, 100], ['s', 'o', '^'], [0.3, 1.0, 0.3]) :
    ax.scatter([plateau[str(net_size)][str(bs)][1] for bs in batch_sizes], 
               [plateau[str(net_size)][str(bs)][2] for bs in batch_sizes],
               c=batch_color_specs, marker=net_size_mark, s=50, edgecolors='none', alpha=net_size_alpha,
               label=str(net_size))
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('accuracy (%)')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., frameon=False, title='Net Size')
plt.show()
```

---

```
plateau = {}
plateau['30'] = {
    '10':  (80.3961 ,  45.0351 ,  96.1100,   20),
    '20': (132.0082 ,  57.7471 ,  96.4600,   42),
    '40': (129.4380 ,  44.1056 ,  96.1500,   49),
    '80': (120.6937 ,  35.7472 ,  95.5400,   49),
    '100': (173.8619 ,  48.9901 ,  95.8900,   71),
    '200': (191.5136 ,  57.8109 ,  95.2600,   76)}
plateau['60'] = {
     '10': (133.2443 ,  80.0031 ,  97.1900,   25),
     '20': (165.0099 ,  77.2276 ,  97.2400,   41),
     '40': (205.8393 ,  78.1126 ,  96.9700,   60),
     '80': (154.8232 ,  49.9324 ,  96.7100,   49),
    '100': (222.3961 ,  68.9063 ,  97.0500,   72),
    '200': (290.0711 ,  88.5366 ,  96.2300,   94)}
plateau['100'] = {
     '10': (177.3463 , 111.3308 ,  97.7300,   24),
     '20': (234.5564 , 117.5112 ,  97.7900,   42),
     '40': (162.1202 ,  65.7477 ,  97.3500,   35),
     '80': (247.8064 ,  87.5982 ,  97.3800,   59),
    '100': (243.6714 ,  82.2312 ,  97.2100,   60),
    '200': (420.6481 , 139.7030 ,  96.9800,  105)}
```

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes

Comment: @tcaswell: Not helpful.